# How to create a pandas dataframe column using a list of numpy nd-arrays?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 lists of numpy nd-array of dimensions 2 and 1 respectively. I want to create a pandas dataframe using the 2 lists being the 2 columns of my dataframe. I do the following -

```
Mfcc = np.arange(1,11,1)
Mfcc =  np.reshape(Mfcc, (-1, 2))
Mel_spec = np.arange(1,10,2)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Mfcc, Mel_spec)), 
               columns =['mfcc', 'mel_spectogram'])   ### mfcc is 2d and mel_spectogram is 1d
                   
type(df.mfcc[1])   ### returns string, when it should return a 1d array
type(df.mel_spectogram[1])   ### returns string, when it should return float being the first element of the array
```

How can I achieve this and where am I possibly making the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Mfcc = np.arange(1,11,1)
Mfcc =  np.reshape(Mfcc, (-1, 2))
Mel_spec = np.arange(1,10,2)

df = pd.DataFrame({'mfcc': list(Mfcc), 'mel_spectogram': Mel_spec})

df.mfcc[1], df.mel_spectogram[1]
```

This code is working fix your Mfcc and Mel_spec according to this

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but unfortunately this doesn't work for me as well. Try saving the csv and the after loading the csv, type(df.mel_spectogram[1]) is still a string, when I want it to be a np nd-array.

Comment: Hey, to_csv will not be able to hold the datatypes over here. Try to_pickle and then read it as read_pickle.

Comment: Also while asking the question please be specific with all your requirements. Since you have not mentioned that you are dumping it and reading it again from CSV. @SoumyaRanjanSahoo

Comment: Right. I got that working by serializing using pickle but that is not a very memory-efficient approach and hence I needed some help on how to write the data frame. Thanks anyway :)